# Scala. Arguments of nested lambdas with short syntax

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

Please, sorry for my English :(
Let's explain my question by examples. We have an array `a`:

```
    var a = Array(1,1,1,1,2)
```

We can:

1. filter `a`:

   ```
   a.filter( _ < 2 )
   ```
2. Count some elements in a:

   ```
   a.count (_ < 2)
   ```
3. Getting unique elements in the collection:

   ```
   a.filter { i =>
       a.count(_ == i) == 1
   }
   ```

**The question is**: how to do third clause but without introducing variable i? Is it possible to write something like:

```
    a.filter ( a.count ( _ == __) == 1 )
```

I understand that I can write this (and it's still short):

```
    a.filter { i => a.count(_ == i) == 1 }
```

But I'm just interested in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this without introducing the variable `i` because it requires mixing variables from two different scopes (what is known as a [closure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_closures.htm)). If we write this without using the `_` placeholder variable, this becomes clearer.

```
a.filter( outer =>
  a.count( inner =>
    outer == inner
  ) == 1
)
```

For every value of `outer` in `a`, we are creating a new function to pass to `count`, in which `outer` is constant and `inner` is passed in as a parameter. `_` can only act as a placeholder for the innermost function it is used in, and so can't be used to replace `outer`. This is why

```
a.filter( outer =>
  a.count(
    outer == _
  ) == 1
)
```

compiles but

```
a.filter(
  a.count( inner =>
    _ == inner
  ) == 1
)
```

does not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention an alternate solution (not simpler, but faster I suppose)

```
a.groupBy(identity).filter{ case (_, v) => v.size == 1}.keys
```

Comment: or `xs groupBy identity collect { case (k, v) if v.size == 1 => k }`

Comment: Or (even faster and more complex): `a.foldLeft(collection.mutable.Map[Any, Int]().withDefaultValue(0))((m, x) => { m(x) += 1; m }).filter(_._2 == 1).keys`. Really only faster for lists of 70 or more elements, though.